# Net::SMPP Connection Timed Out

Tags: perl

I am trying to achieve a bind with an SMSC but I keep getting a timeout error. The connection to the SMSC is via a VPN tunnel. I confirm I can telnet to the SMSC from command line but get a timeout error from the perl script below:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Net::SMPP;
use warnings;

$host = 'xx.xx.xx.xx';
$port = "2038";
$system_id = "SSEMA";
$password = "SSEMA";

my $smpp = Net::SMPP->new_transmitter($host, Port=>$port,
    system_id => $system_id,
    password => $password,
    enquire_interval => 1500000) or die "Could not connect to $host :     [$port] : $!";

if($smpp){ print "Connected ok! \n"; }
```

root@heisenberg:/var/www/html/glomagic# perl smpp_client.pl
Could not connect to xx.xx.xx.xx : [2038] : Connection timed out at smpp_client.pl line 14.

What could be the cause of the timeout error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally resolved the issue.

Apparently Net::SMPP->new_transceiver doesn't like it when you supply arguments other than host and port.

The following worked just fine:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Net::SMPP;
use warnings;

$host = 'xx.xx.xx.xx';
$port = "2038";
$system_id = "SSEMA";
$password = "SSEMA";

my $smpp = Net::SMPP->new_transceiver($host, port => $port)
    or die "Could not connect to $host : [$port] : $!";

if($smpp){ print "Connected ok! \n"; }
```